# Can anyone tell me what font it is?

Tags: fonts, logo, text, font-identification

[image]

a friend of mine want's me to find what font is used in this image.

Comment: Hi Scribble, just having a look at the slanted L and the straight P I'm afraid this is not a font but a custom designed logo.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: Hi Scribble01. That isn't a font. It's a custom design.

Answer (score 2):

I searched your image and use font identifiers. I think it is not a specific font and probably is a typography work. But most similar font which I found is "[Alternity](https://www.fontzillion.com/fonts/pixel-sagas/alternity?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=matcherator_link&utm_campaign=alternity)" with italic style.

[image]